# Prism DelgateComand throws an exception

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, delegatecommand

I have a static delegate command. I'm passing a bool to the constructor. However, it is throwing a runtime exception.

```
public static class myViewModel
{
    public static ICommand myCommand {get; private set;}

    static myViewModel
    {
        //If I change the bool to Object, or to Collection type, no exception assuming that I change myMethod parameter as well to the same type.
        myCommand = new DelegateCommand<bool>(myMethod);
    }

    private static void myMethod (bool myBoolean)
    {
        //To Do
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always, always, always tell us what *type* of exception you got, and what the exception *message* was. They have many, many different exceptions because every one is thrown for a different reason.

But in this case, it looks like the problem is that `bool` is a value type, and the code that executes the command is passing it a `null` for a parameter. But you can't cast `null` to a value type, and trying to do so will cause a runtime exception:

```
object o = null;
//  This will compile, but blow up at runtime. 
bool b = (bool)o;
```

Comment: Thank you. You are absolutely right about the `bool?`  <br/> It is no brainer, I should have included the `exception` . Will keep that in mind. <br/> Thank you

Comment: are you aware of any issue with the forum ? as you can see my previous comment it didn't respect the line break. it left them as text

Comment: @John That's by design. You can't use HTML in comments here. 

You can insert a newline with <kbd>Shift+Enter</kbd> but I don't know if the markdown will respect that; finding out in three, two, one...

Comment: @John No, the markdown doesn't respect newlines in comments. Come to think of it, I should have known that: New users are forever pasting 30-line functions into comments and producing hopeless garble.